# get() method or function

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, socket.io

> Unresolved function or method get().

I'm new in js and node and I got stuck with this while trying to make a chat using sockets. Here is the code:

.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8888);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('send message', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>glupi chat</title>
    <style>
        #chat{
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <form id="send-message">
        <input size="35" id="message">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

<script src='jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    $document.ready(function () {
        var socket = io.connect();
        var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
        var $messageBox = $('#message');
        var $chat = $('#chat');

        $messageForm.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
            $messageBox.val('');
        });

        socket.on('new message', function (data) {
           $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
        });

    });
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, I have every module and library that I need installed.

Comment: Please, post the error stack trace.

Comment: Is the error being thrown in the browsers or nodes console?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  You show us code, but don't tell us exactly where you got stuck, don't include any of your debug information and don't tell us exactly what you want help with.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206001724-Node-JS-app-post-unresolved-function-or-method-post- Googling helps

Comment: there is no error in console only the "unresolved ..." in .js and in .html i have "cannot resolve directory 'socket.io'.. @ChrisSatchell i tried installing that one, same thing. When i open .html everything looks as expected, only when i try to send a message nothing happens.

Comment: @ChrisSatchell - the route `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is automatically handled by the server-side socket.io when you initialize it's server.

Comment: You do not show a server-side route for loading `'jquery-3.2.1.js'`.  node.js does not serve ANY files by default.  If you want that file served from your server back to the client, then you have to create a route that covers it.

Comment: @jfriend00 how do i do that ?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell it shows the whole file.. that one is right.

Comment: @ChrisSatchell - Please see my previous comments.  `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is handled by the socket.io server-side library automatically.  The jQuery file has no route though.

Comment: You can either use `express.static()` to set up a folder of static files or you can change the URL for your jquery file to point to one of the public CDNs or you can make a specific route for the jQuery file in your server with `app.get(...)` just like you did for `app.get('/', ...)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 SO hadn't loaded all comments, got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have no route for the jQuery file you specify with this:

```
 <script src='jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
```

A nodejs express server does not server ANY files by default so unless you have a general purpose route for your static files or a specific file for that jQuery file, your express server will not know how to serve that file when the browser requests it.

You have several possible choices for how to fix that:

1. Change the jQuery URL in the script tag in your web page to point to one of the public CDNs for jQuery.  There are often performance advantages to doing this.  For example, you could change to this: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.
2. Use `express.static()` on your server to configure a directory of static assets that will be automatically served by express when requested by the browser.
3. Create a specific route for the jQuery file just like you did with your exist app.get('/', ...)`that responds to the`/` GET request.